# Condition in PHP class

Tags: php, oop

I have login.php and signup.php. Both send POST requests to the controller class.

How can I identify which script the request is coming from?

using `isset($_POST['signup'])` was working perfectly, but then

```
public function __set($name,$value)
```

in the `signup()` function gives an error.

```
<?php

class Controller{

    public $model;      
    private $full_name;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $user_name;

    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
            $this->full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
            $this->email = $_POST['email'];
            $this->password = $_POST['password'];
            $this->user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        }
    }

    public function __set($full_name,$value){
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone want more explanation,kindly comment here :)) I'll explain more!

Comment: well, `public setter` is a syntax error. it's written `public function __get()`. rtfm?

Comment: Oops, I tried public function __set(), let me edit question.

But it gaves error unexpected public.

I used this setter in a method in the class.

Comment: function definitions are not to be used in functions, only in general class scope.

Comment: there's a reason I edited your question. keep noise out of your question and ask the question at the top, please

Comment: Okay, so suggest me please what Can I do? 
Hope you got my problem :( Any idea?

Comment: yeah, put `public function __get()` in your class, not in a function.

Comment: But both signup.php & login.php form is sending request to this class. So there are a lot of difference in the fields of them.

Comment: this has nothing to do with it. you have two problems 1. you do not understand where to place your code. methods go in class scope. 2. your controller is too specific is it's being constructed with the fields in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965139/condition-in-php-class?noredirect=1#comment51838486_31965139)

> But it gaves error unexpected public. I used this setter in a method in the class.

class methods go in the general class scope, not in functions.

```
class foo {
    public function __get() {
    }
}
```

[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965139/condition-in-php-class/31966128#comment51838862_31965139)

> But both signup.php & login.php form is sending request to this class. So there are a lot of difference in the fields of them

it makes no sense that your controller is validating your fields in the constructor. Either make it a `LoginController` and `SignupController`, or have a separate class validate your inputs.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm going to create LoginController & SignupController!

Answer (score 1):

you can add a hidden input on your forms.  for example on the login form you can add

```
<input type="hidden" name="requestType" value="login" />
```

and on the signup form

```
<input type="hidden" name="requestType" value="signup" />
```

then on your PHP script you can get the value of the hidden input

```
$_POST['requestType']
```

Comment: I also tried that. 
but in my php class how can i use condition because condition in a class is not allowed.
I know I can check it by using if($_POST['requestType'] == "login") 
dothis();

but I'm talking about condition in my class. o_O